# Minimum number of partitions of a set such that the same pair must occur in a block in at least half of them

Tags: co.combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics, extremal-set-theory

For positive integers $k$ and $n$, let ${S} = \{1,\dots,k\ n\}$. Consider $\ell \ge 3$ partitions $P_1,\dots,P_\ell$ of ${S}$, where each $P_i$ splits ${S}$ into $n$ blocks all of size $k$.

**Question:** What is the smallest $\ell$ such that there must exist $x,y \in {S}$ with the property that $\{x,y\}$ is a subset of some block in at least a half of the partitions?

Notes:

- I tried to apply the probabilistic method for some time, and this might be useful for showing that there exist $\{x,y\}$ for each *pair* of partitions, but finding a single $\{x,y\}$ that is in many partitions appears to be difficult using this approach.
- Even an asymptotic bound would be interesting.
- Instead of requiring $\{x,y\}$ to be in at least half of the partitions, any constant fraction of $\ell$ would be fine too.
- *This question was previously posted on math.stackexchange.com but did not get any comments/answers.*

Comment: Do you exclude the trivial $\ell=1$?

Comment: Yes $\ell \ge 3$ according to the assumptions.

Comment: If we consider Kirkman's schoolgirl problem (with $n=5$ and $k=3$) there are $15! \frac{13}{42}$ sets of seven partitions such that no pair occurs twice. Combining disjoint sets of partitions would allow you to get a large lower bound for the constant fraction $\frac17 + \varepsilon$.